# Extract files from password protected zip folder in R

Tags: r

I am trying to unzip some .zip files in REMOTE server. 
I have tried the exact steps suggested by Kim, and modified 7z to zip.

[Unzip password protected zip files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665451/unzip-password-protected-zip-files-in-r)

However, it does not work for for me. Any idea where went wrong?

```
file_list <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/Username/Documents", pattern = ".zip", all.files = T)

pw = readline(prompt = "Enter the password: ")

for (file in file_list) {
sys_command = paste0("unzip ", "-P ", pw, " ", file)
system(sys_command)

}
```

I have a zip file called "Data Science Lifecycle.zip".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably space problems? Try changing the name to `Data_Science_Lifecycle.zip`?

Comment: I've had problems with spaces in filepaths in the past. Try puttingthe filepath/filename into quotes, like this: `example <- "\"my archive.zip\""`

Comment: You can print(sys_command) and run at the windows terminal and see if it was working fine?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to unzip .7z & .zip format password protected files.

```
system("7z x test.7z -ptest") #working for .7z extension files, pw: test
system("7z x test.zip -ptest") #working for .zip extension files, pw: test
```

I have missed out one of the steps, which is to add 7-Zip program to R PATH.

```
if(dir.exists("C:/Program Files/7-Zip/")) 
{   
    paste0("7-Zip exists!")
    old_path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
    Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(old_path,"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\", sep = ""))
}
```

Reference URL:

1. [r system doesn't work when trying 7zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116017/r-system-doesnt-work-when-trying-7zip)
2. https://community.rstudio.com/t/adding-to-the-path-variable/12066

Hope it helps!

Comment: Tried this but had an error 127. Where is `test.zip` located in your example?